# How to trigger infinite scroll from within a lightbox gallery - Django / FancyBox / Waypoints.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, fancybox, infinite-scroll

**The objective :** I'm trying to build a photo gallery app using Django with justified layout, infinite scroll and a lightbox.

I have followed the [following tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html) for the infinite scroll using django pagination and waypoint.js, the justified layout is using [Justified Gallery](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/) and I try to use [Fancybox](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) for the lightbox (any lightbox could do the trick, but I like the clean look of this one). At this point, each of these is working fine when taken individually.

**The issue(s):** My photo gallery contains 100 images. When loading the page on desktop, 36 thumbnails are loaded. If I scroll down, next pages/thumbnails are correctly loaded. But if I use the lightbox before scrolling, I'll be stuck with these 36 images. So at the moment, I am mostly looking for a way to trigger the lazyloading of the page from within the lightbox gallery, without having to exit the lightbox and scroll down.

I found many stackoverflow posts about including the new images to the lightbox (which will probably be my next challenge, tbh), but not much information about how to call next pages/images from within a lightbox.

Being some kind of js/jQuery noob, any help is welcome as i'm not even sure if it is the right way to do it.

Here, you'll find the template of the gallery.html page. It is clearly not a 'minimum reproductible example' as it would probably be the whole app (still possible if needed), but I can provide more code if asked.

```
{% load static %}

{% block head %}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- scripts used for the justified layout -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'gallery/justified-gallery/justifiedGallery.min.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'gallery/justified-gallery/jquery.justifiedGallery.min.js' %}"></script>

<!-- scripts used for the infinite scrolling  -->
<script src="{% static 'gallery/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'gallery/js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>

<!-- scripts used for the lightbox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<div style="margin-left: 100px; margin-right: 100px;">
    <div class="infinite-container justified-gallery" id="my_gallery">

        {% for picture in pictures %}
        <div class="infinite-item">
            <a href={{ picture.picture.url }} data-fancybox="gallery">
                <img alt=" caption for image 1" src={{ picture.picture_thumbnail.url }}/>
            </a>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div class="loading" style="display: none;">
        Loading...
    </div>

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">More</a>
    {% endif %}

</div>
{% endblock %}


{% block script %}
<script>

    // Initialize the justified layout
    $('#my_gallery').justifiedGallery({
        rowHeight: 280,
        lastRow: 'nojustify',
        margins: 20
    });

    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
        element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
        onBeforePageLoad: function () {
            $('.loading').show();
        },
        onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
            $('.loading').hide();

            // re-organize layout after loading
            $('#my_gallery').justifiedGallery('norewind');
        }
    });

</script>{% endblock %}
```

ps: this is my first stackoverflow post, do not hesitated to tell if I need to adjust anything
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

fancybox provides callbacks to allow you to execute your code at any point in the workflow, for example, before/after image is loaded, you can find examples in the docs - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#events

Anyway, 100 images is not such a big deal, because only 3 slides (current and next/prev) are existing at the same time, therefore I am not sure if it is worth to make such efforts.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. 

My post was not clear (i'll edit it). My page contains the thumbnails and the number of picture accessible from fancybox is equal to the number of thumbnails loaded in the page. 

My current issue is more about how to trigger the loading of thumbnails while the user is using the lightbox (then, add them to the fancybox instance). I'm currently tinkering around window.scrollTo() (but it feels a bit hacky), so the events may be the best place to trigger it.

There will be many more pictures (wedding pics of a friend)

Thanks for the input ;)